# how in reading a direct link and displaying it on localhost

Tags: c#, vb.net

I encountered a problem when I programmed a program that reads live mpd links and then converts them into localhost links

- Problem that succeeded in this idea, but the channel does not work on a player when I put a broadcast link
- I offer you a picture and I hope you can help me with something:

[image]

Comment: Hello Badr, welcome to Stackoverflow! Do you have any code to show? What error or exception are you receiving? See [How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes, please
  Dim flag As Boolean = request.Url.ToString().Contains("beinpr1")


                If flag Then
                    response.ContentType = "video/mp4"
                    response.StatusCode = CInt(HttpStatusCode.OK)



                    array = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(getchannels)

                    context.Response.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "player")

                End If

Comment: Please add your code to your question. Use the Edit link. Be sure to format as code.